# Why doesn't the order of `where` attrs matter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

Recently I started building a filter that sorts my data in sphinx, but the thing is - I ran into an interesting CI bug (?). It doesn't matter in what order I pass my `WHERE` attributes because CI will simply sort the results on its own.

Why do both of these queries return the same old result and is there a way how this could be fixed?

```
$a = $this->db->from('table')
              ->where('id', 1)
              ->or_where('id', 2)
              ->get()->result();

$b = $this->db->from('table')
              ->where('id', 2)
              ->or_where('id', 1)
              ->get()->result();

if ($a == $b) echo 'Equal';
```

Comment: do you have tried to make foreach($a as $a1) AND foreach($b as $b1) - is the same results?

Comment: Well, this code would output `Equal`, so they must be the same.

Comment: A very simple question. Do you see order by in your query? Because i DO NOT see. And if it isn't there, the query will be ordered by default. Makes sense?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sql queries that are generated produce the identical result sets, that's why the object sets are identical. This has nothing to do with CI.  Most sql dbs will optimize the where parameters to execute most efficiently, not by the order you specify them in (barring parenthasis or order of operation rules).

If you want to change the ordering of your result set from your sql db, you need to use an order by.

Comment: What would you suggest to do? Should I do post sorting in the code? It'll eat up my resources, but I don't see any other way how to do this.

Comment: @MatīssJānisĀboltiņš no, use the order by function of the CI orm library to sort.  It will be done in the query, not your code.

Answer (score 0):

Order the results on your own.
Something like:

```
order_by("id=1", "desc");
```

I'm not familiar if it works that way in CI(I'm not familiar with it), but in pure MySQL `order by id=1 DESC` would work.